# Efficient way to sum all the bits values of a variable in Fortran

Tags: fortran

Say I have an integer variable `a` with bit representation `101010`, I need to sum all the bit values `1, 0` together which result `3` in this case. Is there a more efficient way to do than this naive code

```
sum = 0
do i=0, bit_size(a) - 1
    sum = sum + ibits(a, i, 1)
end do
```

Comment: First thing is that you don't use `size` but `bit_size`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/POPCNT.html :

Description:

```
POPCNT(I) returns the number of bits set (’1’ bits) in the binary representation of I.
```

Standard:

```
Fortran 2008 and later
```

Class:

```
Elemental function
```

Syntax:

```
RESULT = POPCNT(I)
```

Comment: Awesome that GNU has this intrinsic function!

Comment: Note it's not just gnu - it's part of standard Fortran

Comment: A SIMD reduction argument can usually result in vectorised code... or at least it does if that is in a module, so it should do it in a main.